# Does every activity need a view?

Tags: java, android

I‘m just starting with android and i‘m wondering whether every activity need its own view or you can manage the ui in the activity itself ? Also it isn‘t pretty clear to me why the xml file belongs to the activity and not to the view

Answer (score 4):

Any activity that has a UI needs a View.  Activities handle a UI by displaying the View you set as the content view via setContentView.  Activities have no direct drawing functions.

There are a few situations in which you may have an Activity with no View that just does some processing, but its generally a hack to get somewhere else-  like an Activity that acts as a router.

Comment: But you can add the view programmatically or in the xml file of the activity , correct me if im wrong. In which situation do you use which way?

Comment: You can do it either way. Generally you prefer xml, and only do it programmatically if the to its a single vote, or of is unknown at compile time